# Saving dates in NSUserDefaults xCode

Tags: date, plist, nsuserdefaults, save

I am trying to save some dates in NSUserDefaults (each day user enters date and for example weight and saves it). I have no idea on how to do that. I have been looking for solution to this for quite some time. Should i try plists instead?
Thanks

Comment: Also, this has **nothing** to do with Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

> I have no idea on how to do that.

That means you haven't read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html), which is a *sin.*

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"CurrentDate"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have a lot of data it is best to use something other than nsuserdefaults.  In this case a file could be ok, such as a plist. If you do want to use nsuserdefaults here is simple example.

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
//check if nsuserdefaults has the member value set and if not show them the "login" screen
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *member = [defaults stringForKey:@"member"];

if (![member isEqualToString:@"ValidMember"]) {
    ...do some stuff
}
```

}
writing to nsuserdefaults use this

```
  if ([trimMemberLastName caseInsensitiveCompare:[_memberList objectForKey:memberNumber]] == NSOrderedSame){
    //set a value in nsuserdefaults so we never have to check this
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@"ValidMember" forKey:@"member"];
    [defaults synchronize];

    return YES;
}
```

Also here is example for a plist file:

```
- (NSString *) getFilePath {
//get filepath
NSArray *pathArray = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
return [[pathArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"saved.plist"];
```

}

- (void) saveData {
  //save data
  NSArray *value = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[myTextField text],[myDatePicker date], nil];
  if ([value writeToFile:[self getFilePath] atomically:YES]) {
      NSLog(@"it wrote the file");
  }
  NSLog(@"value = %@", value.description);

}

- (void) loadData {
  //load data
  NSString *myPath = [self getFilePath];
  NSLog(@"myPath = %@", myPath.description);
  BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myPath];
  if (fileExists) {
      NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myPath];
      myTextField.text = [values objectAtIndex:0];
      NSLog(@"myTextField = %@", [values objectAtIndex:0]);
      myDatePicker.date = [values objectAtIndex:1];
      NSLog(@"myDatePkcer = %@", [values objectAtIndex:1]);
  }
  }